# Inclusion of sources from platform specific paths in multiplatform C++ program

Tags: c++, include

How to include multiple sources from platform specific paths in C++ ?
I tried to do following

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _WIN32

static const string INCLUDE_DIR = "C:\\Users\\......";

#else

static const string INCLUDE_DIR = "/home/.......";

#endif

#include INCLUDE_DIR + "someuserlib.h"
```

but it says `#include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You may use MACRO:</strike>

```
#ifdef _WIN32
# define INCLUDE_DIR "C:\\Users\\......"
#else
# define INCLUDE_DIR "/home/......."
#endif

#include INCLUDE_DIR "someuserlib.h"
```

But it seems more correct to use relative path (if possible)

or to use the include switch in your build chain directly:

```
g++ -I "C:\\Users\\..." ..
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the first possibility gives `[Warning] extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]` `[Error] C:\\Users\\.......\\: No such file or directory`

Comment: So, is there a correct way to set `INCLUDE_DIR` just in the code ?

Answer (score 2):

`#include` is a macro, thus is processed before INCLUDE_DIR variable.

But more importantly, there is no need to set backslash in include, forward slash is the correct way for all platforms. The precompiler will internally deal with the differences.

Also setting absolute paths is a very bad idea from portability perspective. It should always be relative (the *baseline* can be set separately through build flags).